# Website redirects to the default cPanel error page in specific countries

Tags: dns, cpanel, centos, whm

I am using CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 xenhvm and WHM 11.50.2 (build 0).
I have no rules in my ModSecurity and no IP or region specific restrictions from htaccess.  The DNS zone was also checked and seems to be correct.

Where else can I check to understand what can cause my site in specific country to  redirect on cPanel default error page (`/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`).

Comment: What countries do/don't work?

Comment: I am checking now for Dublin (Ireland). Maybe in other country too.

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue... when did you last change your name servers or DNS A records?

Comment: Over one year ago , but the problem is that I don't know how long the website isn't available in that country

Comment: How you testing? VPN?

Comment: No I have reported about that from person for whom site need to be available and he located at dublin, and testing using this tool https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an issue with passing the domain name requested in the request header. The only reason why the default page will show is if the request header does not identify which domain name is being requested from the server, essentially as in if the user was putting the servers IP address directly into the browser address bar.

This does not sound like a DNS issue, rather it sounds like an issue in the request and communications stream. It is possible that either there is an issue with the end users machine or browser, or there is an issue with some upstream network which is malforming the request. Based on what you have stated this would not appear to be a DNS issue nor would it appear to be an issue on your end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , yes it seems domain is missing or something else from request header, but how this was possible cant understand before finishing work on that project , so now I haven’t even possibility to test more to understand what exactly was wrong.